# Consider joint p.d.f. $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=C_1e^{-x-y}$, where $0<x<y<\infty$. Find $C_1$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Consider joint p.d.f. $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=C_1e^{-x-y}$, where $0<x<y<\infty$ with continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$. Find $C_1$.

---

Not sure how to approach this. The main property that I am using is

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(u,v) \, du \, dv=1$$

Given the properties of $x$ and $y$ how do we develop a definite integral s.t. we can find the constant?

Comment: The region of integration is $0<x<y<\infty$ so try $\int_0^{\infty}\int_u^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(u,v)dvdu$.

Comment: It's $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^yf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy\:$  or  $\:\int_0^{\infty}\int_x^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture of where the joint density "lives." After you have done that, the way(s) to express your integral as an iterated integral may be obvious.

In this case, because of the symmetry, we can cheat a bit. The integral is half the integral over the whole first quadrant. So we want $\frac{C_1}{2}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\,du\right)\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-v}\,dv\right)=1$. But the integrals are each $1$, so $C_1=2$.